# How to add *or* update columns in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an existing DataFrame, and a method that computes a few columns to add to that DataFrame. I currently use `pd.concat([left, right], axis=1)`. When I call this method a second time, however, it adds the columns again (with the same name).

With the following sample data frames `left` and `right`:

```
left = pd.DataFrame({'one': [1, 2, 3], 'two': [2, 3, 4]})
print(left)

   one  two
0    1    2
1    2    3
2    3    4

right = pd.DataFrame({'one': [22, 22, 22], 'NEW': [33, 33, 33]})
print(right)

   one  NEW
0   22   33
1   22   33
2   22   33
```

I am looking for a `foo` method whose result is the following:

```
left = left.foo(right)  # or foo(left, right)
print(left)

   one  two  NEW
0   22    2   33
1   22    3   33
2   22    4   33
```

And, importantly, if I call `left.foo(right)` a second time, I want the result to stay the same.

`pd.join` raises an error when a column already exists, `pd.concat` doesn't overwrite existing columns, `pd.update` only overwrites existing columns but doesn't add new ones.

Is there a function/method to do what I want or do I have to write one myself?

---

**Solution**: The solution that worked for me, combined from the two answers below, is:

```
result = left.\
        drop(left.columns.intersection(right.columns), axis=1).\
        join(right)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take [`intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) and [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) columns then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on `index` :

```
left = left.drop(left.columns.intersection(right.columns),1).merge(right, left_index=True, right_index=True)

print(left)
   two  one  NEW
0    2   22   33
1    3   22   33
2    4   22   33
```

Comment: Well, yes, that works in the example I posted. But imagine each DF has many columns, and you don't know in advance which ones of `right` already exist in `left`. The resulting workaround would be my alternative if pandas doesn't have this implemented already.

Comment: Thanks! It needed a small edit, `left.columns.intersection` instead of `left.columns.difference`, but it works like this. I changed it a bit, see the update at the bottom of my question

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple method that will update existing columns
or add new ones if needed:

```
left.loc[right.index, right.columns] = right
print(left)

   one  two  NEW
0   22    2   33
1   22    3   33
2   22    4   33
```

The index keys from `right` must be in `left` already, but the columns from `right` will be added if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution, but it only add new columns, not overwrite:

```
left = pd.concat([left, right[right.columns.difference(left.columns)]], axis=1)

left = pd.concat([left, right[right.columns.difference(left.columns)]], axis=1)
print (left)
2   22   33
   one  two  NEW
0    1    2   33
1    2    3   33
2    3    4   33
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution. I just wanted to add a simple change if right have more rows then left, the proposed solutions will not work. However the fix is simple just add how="right" to the join:

```
result = left.drop(left.columns.intersection(right.columns), axis=1).join(right, how="right")
```

Comment: Thanks for submitted an answer.  It would be very helpful to show an example so people can better understand how this solves the case of more rows in right versus left.